# Question on the standard algebraic topology proof that a subgroup of a free group is free

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, free-groups

I have a question on the standard algebraic topology proof that a subgroup of a free group is free. My understanding of that proof (mostly from Hatcher's topology) is as follows:

1. We define a topology on a graph as a $1$-complex.
2. We show that the fundamental group of a graph is the free group generated by one symbol for each loop in the graph.
3. We show that a covering space of a graph is again a graph.
4. We then argue as follows: Given a free group $F$, construct a graph $G$ whose fundamental group is isomorphic to $F$ (as Hatcher notes, this graph can be a wedge of circles). Then using the theory of covering spaces, any subgroup $H \leq F$ corresponds to the fundamental group of some covering space of $G$, which is a graph by item 3. Thus $H$ is a free group by item 2.

My concern is whether this applies when $F$ is infinitely generated - in order to apply the standard results from covering spaces, don't we need to know that the graph $G$ we construct is semilocally simply connected? But (at least visually) if $F$ is a countably infinite set, I image that $G$ looks like the infinite earring, which is famously *not* semilocally simply connected.

I suspect that there is some difference I am missing between the topology of the infinite earring as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the topology of a graph on one vertex with infinitely many loops at that vertex as a $1$-complex, but I'm not sure I know enough about CW-complexes to see what that difference is.

Comment: The induced topology of the hawaiian earring is different from the topology on an infinite bouquet of circles. Any open neighborhood of the common point in the hawaiian earring contains all but finitely many of the circles, but there are open neighborhoods of the common point of the infinite wedge that contain no complete circle. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69698/742).

Comment: I see, thank you for the response!

Comment: And one reflection of the difference between the infinite earring and an infinite bouquet of circles is that the fundamental group of the infinite earring is not free.